# SQL to Linq with aggregate function

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to do this in LINQ.
Can you guys help me to do this?
There some tool to help me with this conversion?

```
SELECT
CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA,
SUM(COALESCE(LOCAL_MOVEL, 0))           AS LOCAL_MOVEL,
SUM(COALESCE(LOCAL_FIXO, 0))            AS LOCAL_FIXO,
SUM(COALESCE(DDD_MOVEL, 0))             AS DDD_MOVEL,
SUM(COALESCE(DDD_FIXO, 0))              AS DDD_FIXO,
SUM(COALESCE(EXTERNA_INTERNACIONAL, 0)) AS EXTERNA_INTERNACIONAL
FROM (
SELECT
CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA,
CASE WHEN TIPO = 'SELM'  THEN SUM(VALOR) END AS LOCAL_MOVEL,
CASE WHEN TIPO = 'SELF'  THEN SUM(VALOR) END AS LOCAL_FIXO,
CASE WHEN TIPO = 'SENM'  THEN SUM(VALOR) END AS DDD_MOVEL,
CASE WHEN TIPO = 'SENF'  THEN SUM(VALOR) END AS DDD_FIXO,
CASE WHEN TIPO = 'SEI'   THEN SUM(VALOR) END AS EXTERNA_INTERNACIONAL
FROM CAD_BILHETES
WHERE ID_PRODUTO IS NULL 
AND ID_COMPETENCIA = 60 
AND CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA IN (14, 160) 
AND TIPO IN ('SEI', 'SELM', 'SENF', 'SELF', 'SENM')
AND VALOR <> 0
GROUP BY TIPO,CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA
) TAB
GROUP BY CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA
```

Comment: It should definitely be possible - LINQ itself is quite powerful.  What does your current progress look like?

Comment: Try to include some code that you tried and describe where it is your are failing. That being said, [linq pad might be of use](http://www.linqpad.net/) to you.

Comment: I'm trying to cast this code into linq to sql.
My progress is less then 0

Comment: In the sub-select with the `CASE WHEN`, do the columns that don't match the case return `NULL`?

Comment: First you need some data to work with LINQ, so you need to choose, are you using LINQ to a generic object? Or using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously untested. Also, uncertain if `null` tests are needed or how they will react through SQL translation. It may be preferable to change the first query to return 0 when not matching and then just sum the results, but I wasn't sure the datatype of the columns.

```
var tab = from cb in CAD_BILHETES
      where cb.ID_PRODUTO == null && cb.ID_COMPETENCIA == 60 && (new[] { 14, 160 }).Contains(cb.CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA) &&
      (new[] { "SEI", "SELM", "SENF", "SELF", "SENM" }).Contains(cb.TIPO) && cb.VALOR != 0
      group cb by new { cb.TIPO, cb.CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA } into cbg
      select new { cbg.Key.CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA,
          LOCAL_MOVEL = (cbg.Key.TIPO == "SELM" ? cbg.SUM(cb => cb.VALOR) : null),
          LOCAL_FIXO = (cbg.Key.TIPO == "SELF" ? cbg.SUM(cb => cb.VALOR) : null),
          DDD_MOVEL = (cbg.Key.TIPO == "SENM" ? cbg.SUM(cb => cb.VALOR) : null),
          DDD_FIXO = (cbg.Key.TIPO == "SENF" ? cbg.SUM(cb => cb.VALOR) : null),
          EXTERNA_INTERNACIONAL = (cbg.Key.TIPO == "SEI" ? cbg.SUM(cb => cb.VALOR) : null),
      };

var ans = from cb in tab
      group cb by cb.CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA into cbg
      select new {
        CODIGO_DEPENDENCIA = cbg.Key,
          LOCAL_MOVEL = cbg.Sum(cb => cb.LOCAL_MOVEL == null ? 0 : cb.LOCAL_MOVEL),
          LOCAL_FIXO = cbg.Sum(cb => cb.LOCAL_FIXO == null ? 0 : cb.LOCAL_FIXO),
          DDD_MOVEL = cbg.Sum(cb => cb.DDD_MOVEL == null ? 0 : cb.DDD_MOVEL),
          DDD_FIXO = cbg.Sum(cb => cb.DDD_FIXO == null ? 0 : cb.DDD_FIXO),
          EXTERNA_INTERNACIONAL = cbg.Sum(cb => cb.EXTERNA_INTERNACIONAL == null ? 0 : cb.EXTERNA_INTERNACIONAL)
      };
```